# How to recover Message if akka actor goes down for some reason?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-persistence

I want to solve two scenarios :

1. I have a sender Actor and a Receiver Actor how will the sender actor know that the receiver actor is not responding.**Terminated case**' can be used to get a notification but what is the latency or the response time of **Terminated message**. I can't miss even a single message.
2. How can I recover the messages that are currently in the mailbox of the terminated actor?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to develop your own protocol for acknowledging messages and that they've been processed, and retrying those that haven't been processed. See:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/message-delivery-reliability.html

> it is always possible to add stronger reliability on top of basic
>   ones, but it is not possible to retro-actively remove reliability in
>   order to gain more performance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since the time this question was asked, Akka 2.6 introduced (though the API is subject to change) opt-in support for [reliable delivery](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/reliable-delivery.html).  When combined with a durable producer (i.e. one which defines a unique persistence ID and writes messages to durable storage), this can guarantee that sent messages are eventually delivered, at the cost of dramatically decreased throughput (and/or substantial persistence expense).